# Declare all methods virtual for mocking using gtest?

Tags: c++, gcc, mocking, virtual, googletest

Currently I'm trying to implement some basic mocking in my C++-project, using the Google Mock framework (gtest). However, this framework is not really playing nice with non-virtual methods, which require some, IMHO at least, ugly work-arounds (using templating). A simple solution would of course be to simply make every method virtual, but the framework advises against this and this wouldn't really be my preferred solution either.

So, I started thinking, isn't there a way to declare every method virtual for the testing, without changing the actual source files? This could be a flag which would be passed to the compiler, or some CPP voodoo. If this would indeed be possible, what would be the disadvantages of this solution?

Any other ways to mock non-virtual functions (preferably using gtest/gmock though), are appreciated as well.

I'm using GCC and X-Code at the moment, if this is relevant.

Comment: Macro way: `#ifdef TEST #define VIRTUAL virtual #else #define VIRTUAL /*Empty*/ #endif`... :/

Comment: Although I like the simplicity of this approach, it still requires me to place VIRTUAL in front of every method, cluttering readability. Isn't there a way to automatically apply it to every method, possibly within a class?

Answer (score 2):

There's only two ways to get a virtual function:

- declare it virtual
- inherit it (from a base class with same name, same signature, virtual function.)

The first can be done explicitly or through a macro, but that makes for ugly code.
The second can be done with a template base, which usually defaults to something empty, but for testing purposes you instantiate it with a class that mirrors your interface but declares the functions virtual.

```
struct Empty { };

template <class BaseT = Empty>
class YourClass : public BaseT {
public:
    void foo();
};
```

Contrived but enough to show intent.  You can use the above for ordinary, non-virtual usage of your code.  Then, for your test:

```
struct YourClassTester {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual ~YourClassBase() { }
};

YourClass<YourClassTester> testable;
```

Etc.  Of course, this does mean you're testing different code than you are actually using, and it may have differences that are detectible, such as:

- size of class bigger (vtbl)
- memory layout different
- RTTI support valid in tests, not when in production
- Some type-traits results may differ as well, depending on the original class category (is_standard_layout, is_pod, is_trivially_copyable, etc.)

If those don't matter, and you don't mind making the class a template, you can try this approach.